# How to setup client side CoffeeScript from a Node.js application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I would like to find a way to correctly setup client side coffee script:

```
public/coffee/any/directory/any/file.coffee
```

I am currently using:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "grunt": "^0.4.5",
  "grunt-contrib-coffee": "^0.10.1",
  "grunt-contrib-less": "~0.3",
  "grunt-shell": "^0.7.0"
},
"dependencies": {
  "body-parser": "^1.3.1",
  "express": "^4.4.3",
  "mongoose": "^3.8.12",
  "node-curl": "^0.3.1"
}
```

I am bit lost about how to setup correctly this.

- Should I try to provide every mapping js files when I receive a request on `/js/any/directory/any/file.coffee`? If so I have not found how to setup `connect-assets` to serve those js. I have tried to setup `grunt-contrib-coffee` but according to the documentation either you put single file in the configuration, either to build everything to a unique file.
- Should I compile everything to a single file?

I am curious to have your feedback and know your setup on this. I am also curious about how to use source maps.

Please try to be specific and provide working sample code and not too much link with documentation, I am lost among irrelevant old posts and documentations, let's try to keep everything on Stack Overflow.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

My current grunt config:

```
coffee:
  compile:
    options:
      sourceMap: true
    src: ['public/coffee/**/*.coffee']
    dest: 'public/js/compiled.js'
```

The remaining problem being that the generated map is done for a concatenated file and not for every single file.